# How to open data file and use variables in gWidgets2?

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm learning `gWidgets2` in order to make a GUI. 
I want to open the RD data file and calculate statistics of variables.

After running simple code, the data file isn't recognized (only the character of the file name is recognized). Thus, I cannot calculate the means of the variables I want. What's wrong?

This is a part of code.

```
surveillance.gui <-function(){ 

widgets<-list()
win <-gwindow("Public Health Surveillance")

pg<-gpanedgroup(horizontal=TRUE, cont=win,expand=TRUE)
mg<-ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, cont=pg)
tmp<-gframe("File",container=mg,expand=TRUE)

lyout<-glayout(container=tmp)
lyout[1,1]<-gbutton ("Data File...",cont=lyout, handler=function(h,...){
std<-gfile(text="Select Data File...",type="open",
        filter=list("Data files"=list(patterns=c("*.R","*.RData")),
                    "All files"=list(patterns=c("*")))
       )
if(std !="")
  { if(length(grep("\\",std,fixed=TRUE))>0){
       mystr<-strsplit(std,split="\\",fixed=T)[[1]]
           mystr.lth<-mystr[length(mystr)] 
           mydir<-substr(std,1,stop=(nchar(std)-nchar(mystr.lth)-1))
         setwd(mydir)     

 } else if(length(grep("/",std,fixed=TRUE))>0){
   mystr<-strsplit(std,split="/",fixed=T)[[1]] 

   mystr.lth<-mystr[length(mystr)] 
   setwd(mydir)
  } 
   samP <<-std
   svalue(widgets$file)<-samP #location of data directory
  }
  })
  st<-strsplit(svalue(widgets$file),split="\\",fixed=T)[[1]]
  fn <-st[length(st)] 


  dfile<-data(fn)


 lyout[1,2]<-(widgets$file<-gedit(text="",cont=lyout))
 lyout[2,1]<-gbutton("Monitoring year",cont=lyout)
 lyout[2,2]<-(widgets$year<-gedit       (text="",cont=lyout,coerce.with=as.numeric))
 lyout[3,1]<-gbutton("Data Type", cont=lyout)
 lyout[3,2]<-(widgets$type<-gcombobox(c("Daily","Weekly"),cont=lyout))
 lyout[4,1]<-gbutton("Mean",cont=lyout, handler=function(h,...){
                                     mean(dfile@observed) })
 lyout[4,2]<-(widgets$mean <-gedit(text="",cont=lyout))
```

Comment: What is the name that doesn't get recognized? Have you tried stepping through the code manually using e.g. `browser()`?

Comment: Yes, but Is browser()  possible when datafile is already readed in R ? And my data's class is sts[package "surveillance"] with 13 slots. so when  I use browser() , it doesn't contain my data. So I can't use it.

Comment: `browser()` will stop execution of a function and does not depend on any data. This is known as "debugging".

Comment: Check what the value of `fn` is in this call `dfile<-data(fn)`. It should be a name of the data file.